# Displaying data from one model and using a form to update another associated by foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I think this must be very much an elementary Django question but I can't seem to find any documentation that is getting me any closer to solution after a couple of hours of searching.

I have two models - a Question for which there can be one or many Answers. The Answer model refers to the Question model using a foreign key relationship.

I would like the page to serve up a random Question and then allow the user to enter an Answer for that question. I guess where I'm confused is how exactly to use forms or formsets to do this.

Here's my code, stripped down of extraneous elements:

## models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(unique=True)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

## forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'rows':2, 'placeholder':'Enter your question here'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Question

AnswerFormset = inlineformset_factory(Question, Answer)
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    error = False
    question = Question.objects.order_by('?')[0]    

    if request.POST:
        form = AnswerFormset(request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponse("Success")
        else:
            error = True
            return HttpResponse("Error")
    else:
        form = AnswerFormset(instance=question)
    return render_to_response('index.html', {"question": question, "form": form}, context)
```

## template (index.html)

```
<form role="form" id="answer_form" method="post" action="">
<p id="question">{{ question.text }}</p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Answer</button>
</form>
```

As it currently stands, the page loads and displays the Question and a bunch of input fields with existing Answers associated to that Question with 3 additional blank input fields. **I would like to display only one blank input field in which an Answer can be entered.** I'm guessing this means manipulating which widget to use on the formset but I'm not sure how.

The submit action isn't working as it stands and I'm probably way off somewhere. I get a "list index out of range" error and I suspect it has something to do with how I'm trying to save the AnswerFormset POST data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting `inlineformset_factory` indicates that you can pass  keyword argument `extra=1` to cause it to generate one (rather than 3) inline forms as desired:

```
def inlineformset_factory(parent_model, model, form=ModelForm,
                      formset=BaseInlineFormSet, fk_name=None,
                      fields=None, exclude=None,
                      extra=3, can_order=False, can_delete=True, max_num=None,
                      formfield_callback=None):
```

Thus:

```
AnswerFormset = inlineformset_factory(Question, Answer, extra=1)
```

EDIT: Indeed, the `extra` keyword documentation confirms this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets

Comment: Thanks. This eliminates the 3 extra fields shown down to 1, but how to prevent the form from displaying the fields that show the existing Answers already in the database?

Comment: To achieve that, you probably need to build the form using the queryset keyword.  The ModelFormset documentation is similar to the InlineFormset, so it probably works similarly. See this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset